# Example of deep understanding of currying

Tags: haskell, currying

Reading https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying

it states :

> Much of the time, currying can be ignored by the new programmer. The
>   major advantage of considering all functions as curried is
>   theoretical: formal proofs are easier when all functions are treated
>   uniformly (one argument in, one result out). Having said that, there
>   are Haskell idioms and techniques for which you need to understand
>   currying.

What is a Haskell technique/idiom that a deeper understanding of currying is required ?

Comment: Applicative functors are a good example of how currying affects idiomatic Haskell. The `<*>` method of `Applicative` is defined on `f (a -> b)`, a functor of function of one argument, but since all functions are curried, *all* functions are of one argument, so the `<*>` function works with functions of arbitrary arity.

Comment: What is the type of `flip id`? What does it do?

Comment: Perhaps the deepest understanding is required to understand crazy things like `printf`, but I would not advise you to jump straight into that sort of complexity.

Comment: Currying *looks like* some trivial syntax-level shortcut. But it does actually allow you to iterate over an arbitrary number of function arguments. This is how (e.g.) QuickCheck is able to test N-ary functions transparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial function application isn't really a distinct feature of Haskell; it is just a consequence of curried functions.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

In a language like Python, `map` *always* takes two arguments: a function of type `a -> b` and a list of type `[a]`

```
map(f, [x, y, z]) == [f(x), f(y), f(z)]
```

This requires you to pretend that the `->` syntax is just for show, and that the `->` between `(a -> b)` and `[a]` is not really the same as the one between `[a] -> [b]`. However, that is not the case; it's the *exact* same operator, and it is right-associative. The type of `map` can be explicitly parenthesized as

```
map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

and suddenly it seems much less interesting that you might give only one argument (the function) to `map` and get back a *new* function of type `[a] -> [b]`. That is all partial function application is: taking advantage of the fact that all functions are curried.

In fact, you never really give more than one argument to a function. To go along with `->` being right-associative, function *application* is *left*-associative, meaning a "multi-argument" call like

```
map f [1,2,3]
```

is really *two* function applications, which becomes clearer if we parenthesize it.

```
(map f) [1,2,3]
```

`map` is first "partially" applied to one argument `f`, which returns a new function. *This* function is then applied to `[1,2,3]` to get the final result.

Comment: Great answer. The `map` example is perhaps a case where one does not really *need* to understand that currying is happening. An example where partial function application *does* require one to understand currying is e.g. `filter (== 5)` where `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`, and so `(==) 5 :: Eq a => a -> Bool`, or `sortBy (comparing f)` where `comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering`, and so `comparing f :: b -> b -> Ordering`, and so `sortBy (comparing f) :: [b] -> [b]`.