# How does Haskell evaluate this signature?

Tags: haskell, signature, currying, partial-application

`ggt_euklid :: Nat1 -> (Nat1 -> Nat1)`

I am trying to learn partial application, I know that in this case, if the parentheses would be left out, I would get the same result, but I do not know how this signature should be evaluated.

As far as I have understood, parentheses signify that it is a function? Would that not imply that ggt_euklid takes a value Nat1 and returns a function?

Below is the complete function:

```
ggt_euklid x y
| x == y = x
|x>y =ggt_euklid(x-y) y 
|x<y =ggt_euklid x (y-x)
```

Comment: "parentheses signify that it is a function?" No, the `->` signifies that it's a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of deep understanding of currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38362348/example-of-deep-understanding-of-currying)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would that **not** imply that ggt_euklid takes a value Nat1 and returns a
>   function?

**No**, it still imply that `ggt_euklid` takes one argument of type `Nat1` and return a function of type `Nat1->Nat1`, even though, **the parentheses be left out**.

The Arrow `->` always be right-associativity (when no parentheses), i.e.:

```
Nat1 -> Nat1 -> Nat1
```

is equivalent to

```
Nat1 -> (Nat1 -> Nat1)
```

which is corresponding to the function application always be left-associativity. (when no parentheses) for example:

```
ggt_euklid 1 2
```

is equivalent to

```
(ggt_euklid 1) 2
```

Here

```
(ggt_euklid 1) ~ Nat1 -> Nat1
```

and

```
(ggt_euklid 1) 2 ~ Nat1
```

So, no matter whether one or two arguments apply to `ggt_euklid`, it always return a function of type `Nat1 -> Nat1` firstly, if second argument is provided, it applies second argument to the returned function.

Answer (score 4):

You have understood the type signature correctly: it takes one argument and returns a function. That's how "multi-argument" functions in Haskell work: through currying. You can see this in action by trying this equivalent implementation:

```
ggt_euklid :: Nat1 -> (Nat1 -> Nat1)
ggt_euklid x = \y -> result
  where result | x == y = x
               | x > y = ggt_euklid (x-y) y 
               | x < y = ggt_euklid x (y-x)
```

Here I've introduced this fairly pointless `result` variable as a thing to use your pattern guards on, but the idea is the same.